# 100% disk usage on windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, filesystems

I've a windows 10 copy running in my core i5 second gen laptop. Now there is this issue where the hard disk usage goes to 100% and the system doesn't respond for a few seconds to even few minutes. I've run process monitor, resource monitor and found that the system uses the disk so much. This doesn't happen when the pc is on idle rather, if I open a folder or any other window, the hard disk usage spikes to 100% and be there for a long time! which is unusual.

I looked at the event log and there I saw a lot of events with the following message.

```
The start type of the Windows Modules Installer service was changed from demand start to auto start
```

I couldn't find what is wrong with the system. I use bitdefender 2015 antivirus and tried switching it off. Then again I disabled windows search, indexing service and all possible solutions I could find over the internet. Installed Ccleaner and did a registry clean and a system cleanup. Nothing worked and now the system is unusable! I cannot re - install windows since I don't have most of the software I've already installed.

If it helps the laptop is a `Dell Inspiron n5110`. Please help me..

Comment: What does resource monitor show is actually using the drive?

Comment: Every single time this has happen to me, eventually the HDD in question, would completely fail.  So when I see questions like this, which indicate huge delays between I/O events, I always indicate the problem is likely caused by the fact your HDD is about to fail.  I suggest you replace the HDD just to be on the safe side.

Comment: It shows that the `system` uses the disk.

Comment: @ramhound : I actually replaced a hard disk thinking that the hard drive was about to fail. This is the new hard drive bought 1 month back

Comment: You bought a new (used) HDD or a new HDD?  The `N5110` came with Windows 7 which means its at least 5+ years old.  Even if the drive is new it could still fail within a month.  So provide us the S.M.A.R.T data on the drive so we can rule that out.

Comment: I bought a brand new hard drive! u mean the laptop could fail or the brand new hard could fail. if the HDD could fail, how come?

Comment: any idea on the issue?

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you log in in Safe Mode?  What about if you disable *all* 3rd party start-ups and services? Have you ensured your drivers are the most up-to-date versions offered by their manufacturers?

Comment: Install the WPT from the Win10 SDK (https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and run this command to capture a xperf trace of the disk usage: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60

Comment: have you captured a trace of the disk activity?

Comment: I was unable to capture anything because after few hours, the pc was un usable! even if I restart and try to install anything, the system crashes. I was running on windows 10 so I downgraded to windows 8 and the pc is running okay!

Comment: ok. Microsoft will release the first larger Win10 update this month. Try this updated Win10 again and see if it fixes your issue

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with certain ACHI devices. Microsoft has provided a solution: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3083595

If you follow these steps (taken from the article) your problem should be resolved.

> 1. #### Identify if you are running the inbox AHCI driver (StorAHCI.sys):
>
>    1. Open a command prompt with administrator privileges. Then type the following command in the command prompt window and hit Enter: `devmgmt.msc`
>    2. Under IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers right-click on the AHCI controller node and select Properties. This node is usually called “Standard SATA AHCI Controller.”
>    3. Navigate to the driver tab and click Driver Details.
>    4. If you see “StorAHCI.sys” in the list, you are running the inbox driver.
> 2. #### Disable MSI for the controller in the registry:
>
>    1. In the same properties window opened in step 1.2, navigate to the Details tab and select Device instance path from the Property drop-down menu. Note this path.
>    2. Open the registry editor by typing regedit in the previously opened command prompt.
>    3. Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\<AHCI Controller>\Device Parameters\Interrupt Management\MessageSignaledInterruptProperties`, where `<AHCI Controller>` refers to the device instance path you noted in step 2.1.
>    4. Change the value of the `MSISupported` key from `1` to `0`.
>    5. If you don’t know which controller your boot device is attached to, repeat steps 2.1 through 2.4 for all AHCI controllers found under 1.2.
> 3. #### Reboot the machine.

Comment: I'll check on the answer and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I found CCleaner was the problem on my PC. It was installed and set to automatically check the C: drive at regular intervals. This caused with great problems with the latest version of this app and Windows 10 Edge explorer. Only after I removed it from loading with Windows and choosing manual clean ups did the C:\ drive quiet down and the system run as built.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was Chrome's software_reporter_tool.exe

Start `Resource Monitor` under disk, and you'll see a whole slew of processes run by this guy.

Seems that Chrome scans our drives looking for stuff that might cause issues with Chrome.

A bit of an eye-opener; this article is great.

https://www.ghacks.net/2018/01/20/how-to-block-the-chrome-software-reporter-tool-software_reporter_tool-exe/