# Even a Vanilla barely used Windows 10 has very high Disk usage upon startup/return from standby

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, performance

Got a new Asus laptop with Windows 10 is always getting pounded by Disk usage = 100% when starting, booting, and then at various points of the day.

I reformatted my windows 10 machine to try to fix it. It was much faster for a few days then got slow again. I have scanned the machine, no viruses or malware that I know of.

I see all sorts of Disk pounders like:

- Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry
- Cortana
- Superfetch
- Search indexer
- WMI
- Other Service Hosts like Windows Event Log
- Antimalware executable

There may be more to this list, and I only see Windows-system executables and services. Once again, no reason to believe I have malware. Fresh system here.

This being a vanilla system with only `Starcraft 2` installed is totally killing me how it's so slow upon startup/standby. My mac and linux machines do not suffer this affliction.

Is anyone else dealing with this on the regular? How can I get my windows PC so that it comes back from standby without having disk usage shoot up to 100% for several minutes? I'm about to leave Windows forever. Could it somehow be my laptop hard drive in the Asus N550JX?

I have read each of the following and verified that I am not afflicted by any of the things listed in these other posts:

[Windows 8 extremely high disk usage and slow IO](https://superuser.com/questions/591250/windows-8-extremely-high-disk-usage-and-slow-io?rq=1)

- This post talks about windows 8 and is about a system that was used for a while getting worse over time. Mine is a vanilla system.

[100% disk usage on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/992071/100-disk-usage-on-windows-10)

- I do not have ACHI devices

[Windows 10 100% Disk Usage after Startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1182651/windows-10-100-disk-usage-after-startup)

- I already have an SSD that came with this laptop.

Comment: Related: [Windows 8 extremely high disk usage and slow IO](https://superuser.com/questions/591250/windows-8-extremely-high-disk-usage-and-slow-io?rq=1)

Comment: [Windows 10 100% Disk Usage after Startup](//superuser.com/q/1182651)

Comment: Not at all the same question as either one of those 2. Only loosely related with a few tips that might intersect. Has nothing to do with AHCI etc

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1182651/windows-10-100-disk-usage-after-startup - this one might be related those other two are not

Comment: You indicated there is high disk usage, the possible duplicate specifically mentions this is a possible problem, with your AHCI driver.  Please post your analyst, that rules out the problem, described in the possible duplicate I suggested.

Comment: Have you tried to disable Cortana?  You can't disable Telemetry since you are not using Windows 10 Enterprise.  If you were to disable, `SuperFetch`, your performance would decrease.  You could disable the search indexer, but that would of course, prevent you from indexing your files on your system.  Windows Event log isn't the problem.

Comment: Have you verified your disk is healthy?  Long period of times, being unable to access folders and (for example starting task manager), is often associated with a failing disk due to the long I/O events.  Windows will eventually invalidate those I/O requests but it takes awhile.

Comment: i'm going to try a completely separate SSD to verify this is not the problem. I will let you know.

Comment: Use [WPT to analyze the issue](https://superuser.com/a/1148857/174557) instead of hibernation select standby/resume. Drag & drop Disk activity graph to analyze pane and [analyze it](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis)

Comment: Take a boot trace with Windows Performance Toolkit you can download from here: [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-assessment-deployment-kit) Here is a tutorial on how to record a boot trace: [How to use wpr to record boot sequence](https://zinetek.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/how-to-use-wpr-to-record-boot-sequence/) Compress the trace and shere it.

Comment: Update - When I replaced the hard drive with a Samsung solid state drive, now the computer is blazing fast.